# C# WPF - Insert UserControl returned from method into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class that returns a `UserControl` object which I'd like to use in a XAML. I would like to know what is the best way to accomplish this.

For instance, I have the class `HomeView` which exposes a public method `GetNavButton()` that returns a `NavButton` `UserControl`. Before, I will insert the NavButton into my XAML like so:

`<local:NavButton ButtonName="Home" ButtonIcon="Solid_Home"/>`

However, I was wondering if there was some way I could insert my `NavButton` into the XAML something like this:
`<HomeView.GetNavButton() />`

I'm aware I can do this programmatically in the `.xaml.cs` file, but
I was wondering if it is possible to directly do it in XAML since it will be more obvious when working with the XAML designer in Blend.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Learning and thinking: In Xaml, `<Tag/>` and `"{MarkUp}"` is equivalent to `new SomeObject()`, `Binding` is equivalent to link to a property with dynamic updateable. 
But you cannot call method in Xaml in some direct way

Comment: What is the point of this approach? Since apparently your `GetNavButton()`takes no parameters, it seems to return always the very same UserControl . If so, why not just define a NavButton.xaml and refer in the "usual" way (`<local:NavButton/>`)?

Comment: @xiurobert: No. You cannot call a method in XAML but you can bind to a public property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You cannot call method in direct way on Xaml.
But `Binding to a property` can be seen as a way of calling parameterless method in Xaml.

So you can refactor or wrap your method `HomeView.GetNavButton()` as a readonly Property `NavButton`:

```
public /*static*/ NavButton NavButton => GetNavButton();
```

If it's a static member, you can use it in this way:

```
<ContentControl Content="{x:Static HomeView.NavButton}"/>
```

`x:Static` can let you get a public static member value when it initialization.

If not a static member, try this way:

```
 <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding *BIND TO HomeView*}" Content="{Binding NavButton, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Let `HomeView` as `DataContext` of `ContentControl`, and then binding `Content` on `HomeView.NavButton` property.
Note that `Mode=OneWay`, because the property is "readonly". If not set that, it will throw an exception.

Comment: But this is a Hacky approach, I don't recommend that you actually use it. Please consider it only as an exploration of possibility on xaml.